# Discord Bot. bot.loop.create_task(background_task()) don't work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this code:

```
import asyncio
import random

from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

a=['Hello','Hi','Hello World']

async def background_task():
    time = 5 # 86400
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    w = random.choice(a)
    q = "".join(w)
    message = q
    await bot.get_channel(id_channel).send(message)

async def on_ready():
    print('Bot logged as {}'.format(bot.user))


async def on_message(ctx):
    pass

bot.loop.create_task(background_task())
token = 'token'
bot.run(token)
```

I need to loop **background_task()**. But **bot.loop.create_task(background_task())** don't working. What should I do? I will be grateful fo your help.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? This function will only execute once because you dont tell it to loop or anything, and also the first time it is running is possible that the cache is not loaded, which is why you dont see any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while True solve my problem

```
import asyncio
import random

from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

a=['Hello','Hi','Hello World']


async def background_task():
    w = random.choice(a)
    q = "".join(w)
    message = q
    while True:
        time = 5 # 86400
        await asyncio.sleep(time)
        await bot.get_channel(771365589355855883).send(message)

async def on_ready():
    print('Bot logged as {}'.format(bot.user))


async def on_message(ctx):
    pass

bot.loop.create_task(background_task())
token = 'NzcxMzYwMzk4NzAzOTg0NjYx.X5q_Wg.w00I702euybW-Z2AYSQpHIsfifQ'
bot.run(token)
```

Comment: you should remove your token from this answer